# Proper Technique to Post to Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, ember.js

I have a problem posting with Ember to my Laravel API.  I keep getting COR's errors and when I try adding the proper headers to my store method the errors are still there.  I have researched this for one an hour and no results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for my store() method...

```
$statusCode = 200;
$libraries = $request->all();
$library = Library::create($libraries);
$criteria = $library->toArray();
 return Response::json([
     'library' => $criteria],
      $statusCode);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

route start with api is allow here

e.g myapp.com/api/login

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if (!$request->is('api/*'))
  {
    return parent::handle($request, $next);
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include Closure. Will comment again on lunch break. Thanks for the help, I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: your project laravel version??

Comment: Laravel 5.2 and I'm still getting the same errors with the anewer given